Azure.Identity: ManagedIdentityCredential authentication failed
When I try to run the application, I'm getting this exception. The same code is working fine on another machine.
I tried az login also logged in in Azure service authentication in tools->options, but none works.
The exception is thrown from blobstorage client 

Error 12029 calling WINHTTP_CALLBACK_STATUS_REQUEST_ERROR, 'A connection with the server could not be established'.

A host error has occurred during startup operation 'ef3280b7-fc62-48e2-86d9-ecabccf48ff2'.
[2024-10-09T13:05:29.301Z] Azure.Identity: ManagedIdentityCredential authentication failed: Retry failed after 6 tries. Retry settings can be adjusted in ClientOptions.Retry or by configuring a custom retry policy in ClientOptions.RetryPolicy. (An error occurred while sending the request.) (An error occurred while sending the request.) (An error occurred while sending the request.) (An error occurred while sending the request.) (An error occurred while sending the request.) (An error occurred while sending the request.)
See the troubleshooting guide for more information.
https://aka.ms/azsdk/net/identity/managedidentitycredential/troubleshoot.
Azure.Core: Retry failed after 6 tries. Retry settings can be adjusted in ClientOptions.Retry or by configuring a custom retry policy in ClientOptions.RetryPolicy. (An error occurred while sending the request.) (An error occurred while sending the request.) (An error occurred while sending the request.) (An error occurred while sending the request.) (An error occurred while sending the request.) (An error occurred while sending the request.). Azure.Core: An error occurred while sending the request. System.Private.CoreLib: An error occurred while sending the request. System.Private.CoreLib: Error 12029 calling WINHTTP_CALLBACK_STATUS_REQUEST_ERROR, 'A connection with the server could not be established'.
Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'provider')


Please edit your post and paste the code and error message as text, not images.

Please provide your function code @Fsam

Managed Identity works only in Azure.
You have to use DefaultAzureCredential instead in Http triggered Azure functions locally.
Code Snippet:
  [FunctionName("Function1")]
  public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
      [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
      ILogger log)
  {
      string containerName = req.Query["containerName"];

      if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(containerName))
      {
          return new BadRequestObjectResult("Please provide a containerName in the query string.");
      }

      var blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient(new Uri("https://StorageName());
      var containerClient = blobServiceClient.GetBlobContainerClient(containerName);

      bool exists = await containerClient.ExistsAsync();

      if (exists)
      {
          log.LogInformation($"Container '{containerName}' already exists.");
          return new OkObjectResult($"Container '{containerName}' already exists.");
      }

      await containerClient.CreateAsync();
      log.LogInformation($"Container '{containerName}' created successfully.");
      return new OkObjectResult($"Container '{containerName}' created successfully.");
  }

.csproj:
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Azure.Identity" Version="1.13.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Azure.Storage.Blobs" Version="12.22.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions" Version="4.5.0" />
  </ItemGroup>


Able to create the container in Azure Blob Storage:


Portal:

Response when tried to create container with the existing container's name:

